# Perpendicular Projection Operator

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Assume that $Z$ is the perpendicular projection operator onto the column space of $X$, i.e., $C(X)$. We are to show that $(I-Z)$ is the perpendicular projection operator onto  the orthogonal complement of $X$, i.e., $C(X)^\perp,$ and then find the trace, i.e., $\text{tr}(I-Z)$, in terms of the rank of $X$, $r(X).$

$\textbf{My Take:}$

Since $Z$ is a perpendicular projection operator onto $C(X),$ this implies that $$C(Z) = C(X)$$
and $Q = (I-Z)$ is another perpendicular projection operator which projects along the $C(X)$ and onto the kernel i.e., $$N(X) = C(X)^\perp.$$
Now, I am stuck in here, I don't know how to vividly show that $C(X)^\perp = 0,$ since we weren't given any specific matrix, $X$ for any computations.

For the trace, since $(I-Z)$ is another perpendicular projection matrix, then, $$\text{tr}(I-Z) = \text{rank} (I-Z) = \sum_i\sum_j z^2_{ij}$$ Probably, how I tackle the problem is incorrect. I rely on folks here to help.

Answer (score 1):

To show $I-Z$ is an orthogonal projection [on some subspace], you need to verify two things.

- $(I-Z)^2 = I-Z$
- $(I-Z)^\top = I-Z$

This should be straightforward given that $Z$ is an orthogonal projection.

---

To show that $I-Z$ is the orthogonal projection on $C(X)^\perp = C(Z)^\perp$, it suffices (why?) to show $N(I-Z) = C(Z)$. Again, you will use the fact that $Z$ is the orthogonal projection onto $C(Z)$.

---

You are correct that $\text{tr}(I-Z)=\text{rank}(I-Z)$. The rank-nullity theorem will relate this number to $\text{nullity}(I-Z) \equiv \dim N(I-Z)$. Above, we showed $N(I-Z)=C(Z)=C(X)$. Hopefully this is enough to tie everything together.

Comment: I wasn't sure about my presentation. It seems you got almost the same as mine. I welcome diverse views on the problem.